# Cannot convert value of type 'XXX.Protocol' to expected argument type 'XXX.Type'

Tags: swift

I have an app which saves its data in a database and as I rewrite it entirely in Swift I'm facing the following problem.
Basically I have a root class `DatabaseObject` which all objects in the database inherit from. Then at some point I want to declare a protocol that some database objects will adopt. Finally I would like to be able to use that protocol in generic functions but it won't compile.

Here is a simplified code that you can run in a playground :

```swift
class DatabaseObject {
    var id: String

    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol: DatabaseObject {
    func someFunc()
}

func getObject<T: DatabaseObject>(id: String, type: T.Type) -> T? {
    // Fetch the object and returns it
    // [...]
    return nil
}

let object1 = getObject(id: "XXX", type: DatabaseObject.self)
let object2 = getObject(id: "XXX", type: SomeProtocol.self)
```

Last line generates the error *"Cannot convert value of type 'SomeProtocol.Protocol' to expected argument type 'DatabaseObject.Type'"*.

`SomeProtocol` inherits from `DatabaseObject` so I would expect this code to work.

As a workaround I can do that :

```swift
let workaround = getObject(id: "XXX", type: DatabaseObject.self) as? SomeProtocol
```

but I don't like it as it kind of defeats the purpose of making a generic function…

Is this a Swift limitation ? Does anyone have a better idea ?

Comment: See [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

Comment: `protocol SomeProtocol: DatabaseObject` — is it even legal?

Comment: I've seen this question and if I get it right I should try to put `SomeProtocol` in a box and create a struct `AnySomeProtocol` for example. But obviously in this case it won't work as `SomeProtocol` has to inherit from `DatabaseObject`.